# GET method in rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, get

I am working with search forms and want to use GET request in a ruby on rails form . I use something like this

1) in  view

```
form_tag(:action => "actionxyz", :method => "get")
```

2) In routes

```
get 'actionxyz', :controller => :controllerabc
```

When the request is inspected , the following is seen

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/actionxyz?method=get" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
```

Further more in the url I see `/actionxyz?method=get` and not the search string that I have provided. The search string provided appears in the POST data. 
Does that mean that rails is not using GET method or I am wrong in my interpretation.
Please clarify ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's interpreting the method `get` as part of the route the form should go to, instead of an additional options to `form_tag`. So, you must isolate it:

```
form_tag( {:action => "actionxyz"}, :method => "get") do
```

or just

```
form_tag url_path, method: :get do #where url_path is your route
```

Answer (score 2):

The form_tag just needs the URL:

```
form_tag '/actionxyz', :method => "get"
```